# Request Tensor Correction Error for Conv2D model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, training-data

I am using CNN for a kind of linear regression model. I want to predict a particular value based on 2 input variable values. My input data is shown in fig-1. there are 100 samples and I made 20 samples into one set. So I have 5 sets with 20 samples each. 5 output values

```
a = indata[0:20]
a = np.array(a)
b = indata[20:40]
b = np.array(b)
c = indata[40:60]
c = np.array(c)
d = indata[60:80]
d = np.array(d)
e = indata[80:100]
e = np.array(e)

i = (a, b, c, d)
i = np.array(i)
i = np.expand_dims(i, -1)

vi = (e)
vi = np.array(vi)
vi = np.expand_dims(vi, (0,-1))

o = np.array(outdata)

vo = o[4]
o = o[:4]
```

I used the above code to separate the data into 4 sets for training and 1 set for validation.
i - training input  vi - validation input   o-training output  vo-validation output.

Shapes - i --(4,20,2,1)  vi--(1,20,2,1) o--(4,1)  vo--(1,)

```
i = Input(shape=(20,2,1))

x = Conv2D(16,(2,2), strides=2, activation='relu' ,  data_format='channels_last', padding='same')(i)    
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Conv2D(32,(2,2), activation='relu',  data_format='channels_last' , padding='same')(x)   
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

x = Flatten()(x)

x = Dense(320, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(160, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(80, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(i,x)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mse')

model.fit(x=i, y=o,validation_data=(vi,vo),epochs=50, steps_per_epoch=10)
```

When I run this code, I get an error as shown in the fig-3 ...It says "Requested Tensor Correction between nodes 'input-9' and 'input-9' would create a cycle

Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: you try to assign two variables to 'i'.... your X_train and the Input layer... change one of them

Comment: **model.fit(i, o, validation_data=(vi,vo),epochs=50, steps_per_epoch=1)**      I tried this...But it still shows the same error.   'i' is my train input, 'o' is my train output and 'vi','vo' are my validation input and outputs....what do I mention my inputs for model.fit() i**model.fit(input,output,validation_data)** ??  @Marco Cerliani

Comment: please change the name correctly... https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OjUPpNsZ82TAqz6l-kXFiqjEGR85wmGp?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you so much @ Marco Cerliani. The way you showed really helped me to identify and understand my mistake. Was really helpful. Have a good day :)